# Compiler-deduced type for generic lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, type-deduction

In [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/the-c14-standard-what-you-need-to-know/240169034), the following code is presented:

```
std::vector<int> ivec = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector<std::string> svec = { "red", "green", "blue" };
auto adder = [](auto op1, auto op2){ return op1 + op2; };
std::cout << "int result : "
          << std::accumulate(ivec.begin(),
                             ivec.end(),
                             0,
                             adder)
          << "\n";
std::cout << "string result : "
          << std::accumulate(svec.begin(),
                             svec.end(),
                             std::string(""),
                             adder)
          << "\n";
```

If I understand correctly, the compiler will generate an internal class much like this one:

```
template<class T>
class _lambda
{
  public:
  T operator()(T lhs, T rhs) { return lhs + rhs; }
};
```

But what I don't understand is, in this section of the code, adder seems to have two types at the same time: `_lambda<int>` and `_lambda<string>`. How is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the standard 5.1.2/p5 Lambda expressions [expr.prim.lambda]:

> For a generic lambda, the closure type has a public inline function
>   call operator member template (14.5.2) whose template-parameter-list
>   consists of one invented type template-parameter for each occurrence of
>   auto in the lambda’s parameter-declaration-clause, in order of
>   appearance.

Consequently, what is actually generated is:

```
class _lambda {
public:
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    auto operator()(T1 lhs, T2 rhs) const { return lhs + rhs; }
};
```

Comment: Likewise, if arguments are  like`auto && lhs`. then it generates `T && lhs`.. and so on.

Answer (score 8):

Nope. It generates something like this:

```
class _lambda {
public:
    template<class T1, class T2>
    auto operator()(T1 lhs, T2 rhs) const { return lhs + rhs; }
};
```

The class isn't templated. The `operator()` is.

Comment: Likewise, if arguments are  like`auto && lhs`. then it generates `T && lhs`.. and so on.

Comment: @Nawaz in his example they are not

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, the compiler will generate a class looking like this:

```
class _lambda {
public:
    template<class T, class U>
    auto operator()(T lhs, U rhs) const { return lhs + rhs; }
};
```

The two arguments are not necessarily of the same type, the only condition is the existance of a `operator+()` with the regarding argument types.

Look at the demo on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/450140658c098e94).

Comment: Likewise, if arguments are  like`auto && lhs`. then it generates `T && lhs`.. and so on.